# Computer Keeps Restarting Every 5 Minutes

Tags: windows, dragon-naturally-speaking

My computer has randomly started to restart, usually around at around 10 minute intervals.

It happens while using Microsoft Word for work.

So far it's only happened today (around 6 times), and each of those times has been when I'm running Nuance Dragon Naturally Speaking 14 (speech-text program).

However, the program seems to run fine, then the computer restarts, thus I'm not sure if this program is related or not.

I am running Windows 10 Professional, and notice no other problems - I've run a few malware programs to make sure there isn't any viruses and nothing came up, but I'm not a tech-user at all and my boss isn't helping me so I'm stuck unable to work because it keeps restarting :(

Any help would be much appreciated - thank you!

UPDATE:

Still doing it!

Also found out it restarts when I press Control Alt Delete to try to access Task Manager.

These are the issues I can see in the Event Viewer now;

The server {F9717507-6651-4EDB-BFF7-AE615179BCCF} did not register with DCOM within the required timeout. The Sync Host_42ea3 service terminated unexpectedly. It has done this 1 time(s). The following corrective action will be taken in 10000 milliseconds: Restart the service. The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID {D63B10C5-BB46-4990-A94F-E40B9D520160} and APPID {9CA88EE3-ACB7-47C8-AFC4-AB702511C276} to the user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM SID (S-1-5-18) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

Comment: [What information appears in the event logs? Any errors? (Event Viewer)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-information-event-logs-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Here is a screenshot of the Event Viewer (In system mode?) for the last 12 hours.https://s31.postimg.org/wlbie0qej/Screenshot_1.png

Comment: If you leave your computer idle for a while, does it still close/restart?

Comment: It hasn't done yet, so far the only times it has restarted is when I have been using Dragon Naturally speaking. But no idea if that's just coincidence or not. Other process I am doing right now is using Bitlocker to encrypt an external HD, but seems to be working fine. Just a bit confused. Thanks for your help

Comment: Update your audio drivers

Comment: I just checked, and it says all drivers are up to date :/